# Saving relationships in Ember.js and emberFire

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

Lets say I have two models, `Book` and `Chapter`.

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  chapters: DS.hasMany 'chapters', async: true

App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  book: DS.belongsTo 'book', async: true
```

Using emberFire.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend
  firebase: new Firebase('http://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/')

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.FirebaseSerializer.extend()
```

According to [the documentation on relationships](https://github.com/firebase/emberFire#relationships), using the `async: true` option, Firebase would expect my data to look something like the following.

```
{
  'books': [{
    'book_id_1': {
      'name': 'Example',
      'chapters': [{
        'chapter_id_1': true
      }]
  }],
  'chapters': [{
    'chapter_id_1': {
      'name': 'Chapter 1'
    }
  }]
}
```

I can save a `Chapter` just fine, however I can't seem to get the `chapters` property of a `Book` populated with a newly created `Chapter`.

In the chrome console:

```
var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
store.find('book', 'book_id_1').then(function(b) { window.book = b });

var chapter = store.createRecord('chapter', { name: 'Chapter 1' });

chapter.save().then(function() {  // Saves the chapter
  book.get('chapters').then(function(chapters) {
    chapters.addObject(chapter);
    book.save();  // Doesn't append to the chapters object
  }
});
```

The above code does *not* save the `chapters` property on the `book` the way I would expect it to. Any help would be appreciated.

---

### **EDIT**

It looks like the proper way to add the `chapter` object to the `book.chapters` property is:

```
book.get('chapters').then(function(chapters) {
  chapters.addObject(chapter);
  book.save().then(function() {
    chapter.save();
  });
});
```

But if there are validation errors on the `chapter` object, it will be added to the `book.chapters` property but won't be saved (creating an invalid reference). How do you get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Ember-Data has a weird nuance where if something is defined from one relationship as a `hasMany` and the corresponding record as a `belongsTo` it only sends up the attribute if it's  the `belongsTo`.  That being said, you'd need to call `chapter.save()`.  I actually hate this, and I've complained about it before, but I've been to lazy to submit a pull request.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean. Removing the `belongsTo` and rearranging my `save()` calls (ie, first saving the `book` after the chapter is added, *then* saving the `chapter`) fixes the issue, but I have no idea why. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm curious why removing the `belongsTo` from the `Chapter` model partially fixes the issue..

Comment: It's related to how ED decides to serialize a hasMany relationship.  It does it different depending on the corresponding record, you can see me asking about it in the code here, https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/7f752ad15eb9b9454e3da3f4e0b8c487cdc70ff0#commitcomment-4923439